# Ignore Scala Compile Errors Like Java

Tags: java, scala, compilation

How can I skip scalac compile errors like one can with Java?

This causes the compiler to skip the erroneous file, compiling the rest, and leave the crash to run-time.

I use SBT but since it uses scalac, I think it would be a command line parameter for scalac that passes through from SBT.

Update:

My goal is to run the program, and have it fail at run-time when the error is reached.

For example, there can be a main GUI that has no errors with a button to start a server that does.

In Java the GUI will run and fail during run-time when the button to start server is clicked.

In Scala the program won't even run because the GUI file could not compile before the server file does.

Comment: What do you want to reach with this? And what should Scala do with files it cannot compile?

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke My goal is to run the program, and have it fail at run-time when the error is reached.  Updating post with example now.

Comment: Votes to close a legit question?  If you can provide a reason why you voted as such, I will gladly update my post.  This question in particular is one that *will* be asked by many coming from Java.

Answer (score 1):

## Your request is against Scala's principles (don't do it, please)

This should not be possible in Scala, because it is against one of the design principles in Scala: When a program compiles, there won't be runtime errors. Of course this principle doesn't hold in all extreme cases. But people are working hard to cover all the common cases.

If the Scala compiler would provide what you are requesting, I would consider it a bug in the compiler.

## How to make it work (if you still want to do it)

Of course, no one is hindering you to run programs with compile errors. It is possible up to a certain degree.

1. Split your program into several modules (e.g. one core and several plugins)
2. Compile the parts independently. When there is an error in one of the modules, Scala will not compile it)
3. Copy the results (where Scala produced some) together
4. Run the result

You could some kind of dependency injection (e.g. [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) or some plugin infrastructure (e.g. [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html)) to handle the plugins better.

## A personal anecdote (why you should not do it)

For one customer my team and I developed a custom programming language, complete with a runtime and an IDE (based on [Eclipse xText](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/)). In an early version we had a compiler that would compile files with syntax errors. It just added additional tokens (closing brackets, keywords, missing strings or numbers) when needed until the syntax was OK again. Such a tool is very useful for syntax highlighting and completion in files that have compile errors (e.g. because the file is currently work in progress and some parts are missing). But when you run what that compiler produces, the results are hilarious at best and disastrous at worst. We quickly changed the compiler, so it will not emit runable code any more when there are any errors in the source code.

Comment: Thank you for the well written post.  Please allow me to disagree with the design principle.  Having code that does not fail at runtime is the job of the programmer.  A compiler can correct syntax errors but cannot always correct logic errors.  A compiler should be able to skip over syntax errors while informing the programmer of them.  Its the job of the programmer to review these errors.  I know Java will allow this and it is a very mature language.  I am looking into how the eclipse compiler can skip errors and if it is possible to imitate with Scala.

Comment: I should have said the compiler can inform about syntax errors not correct them.  As a solution to this problem, I wonder if I can have the compiler comment out non-compiling lines, and inform these were skipped, and have an exception thrown if reached during run-time.  You said that packages could be skipped if non-compiling, then why shouldn't individual files, or lines?

Comment: @BAR Complete compile units can be skipped, not parts of them (be it packages, files or lines). A compile unit is a set of files that can be compiled on its own. Practically you would run scalac multiple times, once for each compile unit. If there is any error in a compile unit, scalac will fail and not create any binary (class) files for that compile unit.

Comment: That makes sense.  Although I am wondering how to have the compile unit skipped.  I have a file that is not being used by any other files, therefore a compile unit, that halts compilation since it has errors.  Is there a command line hook I need?

Comment: Can you please provide a source for "...because it is against one of the design principles in Scala: When a program compiles, there won't be runtime errors."

Comment: @BAR I have no explicit quote at hand. But if you look for example in the documentation of the collections API, you find the following gem: "The bottom line is that the large majority of misuses will manifest themselves as type errors. It’s not at all uncommon to have programs of several hundred lines run at first try." http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html

Comment: Taken in context, it does not imply that errors at compile time should halt the compile.  It does mean that Scala's type checker should catch all errors at compile time, which is IMO a great feature, while halting the compile is not.

Comment: @BAR type errors will halt the compile run. The compiler doesn't know what code it should emit when there are any compile errors. And type errors are compile errors.